# VS-Code Remote SSH: failed to set up socket - other clients are ok?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

I am trying to connect to my shared server via VS Code Remote-SSH, but get the timeout error every time with the below error message.
This error only occurs with VS Code Remote-SSH, when using another client (Putty, Termius) the connection works just fine.

Please note:
this is a shared server where I have SSH access, but no `sudo` privileges and connect via port `1394`. Also, the error notification popup ultimately says `Could not fetch remote environment`. Since its working well in Putty, my best guess is that there are some settings in VS-Code I need to adjust. Appreciate any insight.

```
[10:46:52.974] Remote server is listening on 17332
[10:46:52.974] Parsed server configuration: {"remoteListeningOn":{"port":17332},"osReleaseId":"Linux","arch":"x86_64","webUiAccessToken":"","sshAuthSock":"","tmpDir":"/run/user/65612","platform":"linux"}
[10:46:52.976] Persisting server connection details to /Users/User/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-MY-SERVER-e5a624b788d92b8d34d1392e4c4d9789406efe8f-0.56.0/data.json
[10:46:52.978] Starting forwarding server. localPort 62979 -> socksPort 62958 -> remotePort 17332
[10:46:52.979] Forwarding server listening on 62979
[10:46:52.979] Waiting for ssh tunnel to be ready
[10:46:52.980] Tunneled 17332 to local port 62979
[10:46:52.980] Resolved "ssh-remote+7b22686f73744e616d65223a225143492d536f75726365227d" to "127.0.0.1:62979"
[10:46:52.981] [Forwarding server 62979] Got connection 0
[10:46:52.996] ------
[10:46:53.034] [Forwarding server 62979] Got connection 1
[10:46:53.035] [Forwarding server 62979] Got connection 2
[10:46:53.055] Failed to set up socket for dynamic port forward to remote port 17332: Socket closed. Is the remote port correct?
[10:46:53.104] Failed to set up socket for dynamic port forward to remote port 17332: Socket closed. Is the remote port correct?
[10:46:53.104] Failed to set up socket for dynamic port forward to remote port 17332: Socket closed. Is the remote port correct?
```

Answer (score 17):

**Edit** `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

**Change** `AllowTcpForwarding` to yes

```
AllowTcpForwarding  = yes
```

**Restart** sshd

```
systemctl restart sshd
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Do you know what might have caused the issue? Because in my setup it worked until yesterday, then gave me this problem.

Comment: In addition, I also had to set `AllowAgentForwarding = yes`.

Comment: Should this be done on the server, or on my own computer? I think the answer should mention that.

Comment: @knia It should be one on the host server, not your computer.